# Database relationship: Shipping Address in Shipping Data

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm building a database for management of my company.

I send the relationships of my database:

[image: Database Relationship]

I would like to introduce a combo box in the "ShippingAddress" Field of the tbl "ShippingData" and validate it from the "AddressID" in the tbl "CompanyAddresses".

As I'm pretty new in Access and Databases. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want a 'cascading' combobox. Would have to first select company ID to limit address choices. This requires VBA. Common topic. Do research and when you have code with specific issue, post question. As is, question is too broad.

Comment: Yes. You understood my question! I'll follow your advice! Thank you very much.